# Should I still use Enums from JAXB Objects in my production code?

Tags: java, enums, jaxb, refactoring

We have this project where JAXB Objects are separated from the production code. We were creating an entity inside the production code (which were based from the JAXB Objects). Those JAXB Objects auto-generated Enumerations as well. What should I do? Should I still use those JAXB enum or create a separate enum inside the production code? Would it be too costly as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "separated from production code"? Do you mean, you use the JAXB classes to parse XML into an object structure and then you map those classes to you application model?

Comment: Sorry, I guess Production code means Application Code.

Answer (score 0):

The options are:

- Implement an separate entity model, use JAXB schema-derived classes only as DTOs, implement entity -> DTO converters.
- Use schema-derived classes directly as entity model.

The first option is more expensive, but you have a cleaner separation between the business logic and the facade layers.

The second option is cheaper, but you're completely schema-driven.

Using schema-derived enums (or other schema-derived classes) in the business logic puts you in the second option. As mentioned, this is fast and cheap and works fairly well - as long as your business logic is completely schema-driven.

But it fails if your business entities have their own meaning. Consider the following questions:

- What happens if the schema will be changed?
- What if you'd need to support multiple schema versions in parallel?
- What if you'd need to support other transfer channel formats, not just XML?
- What if you'd need add to your business entities functionality which you can't (easily) autogenerate?

Clean separation between the business entities/datatypes and the DTOs helps a lot. Changes/requirements described above would only impact one layer, not the business logic or below.

Comment: Thank you it had clarified my question